# has_many through with multiple foreign keys on table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `FeedPost` model that `has_many :flights`. Flights then have an origin_id and a destination_id, which both map to a `locations` table.

The question, is is there a rails way I can call `FeedPost.first.locations` and get all locations for all flights associated with that `FeedPost`?

Doing this:

```
  has_many :locations, through: :flights, source: :origin
  has_many :locations, through: :flights, source: :destination
```

Just returns the destination locations.

I've seen a lot of similar questions, but they all relate to getting the values of each column, not both columns in one call.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to declare `has_many :locations` twice, does it? Instead, how about declaring `has_many :origin_locations` and `has_many :destination_locations` and then creating a method/scope (`all_locations`) that concatenates the results of `origin_locations` and `destination_locations`?

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what jvillian commented, which is in fact an answer

```
class FeedPost < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :flights
  has_many :destinations, through: :flights, source: :destination
  has_many :origins, through: :flights, source: :origin

  def locations
    (origins + destinations).uniq
  end
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I couldn't have said it better myself. ;-)